# Conditional rendering in React (featuring Chart.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently working on a project, and it has many functionalities, one of them is displaying a chart with data provided by controlled inputs. When the app renders, there's no information and the chart is not displayed, so I decided to display a component called ChartCover while no data has been displayed, and using Conditional rendering, I would show the chart to the user if the inputs were filled correctly. But I'm having a problem with this part. The conditional rendering is working, but I have to click my submit button twice(At the first click it replaces the ChartCover with my BillsChart component, but I have to click one more time for the data to appear). Sorry if it's a little bit confusing, but, anyway, I'll show the code snippets below.

(one more thing, the hasTypedIn is initialized in the state as being false, and in a handleSubmit method I just change it to false)

The handleSubmit method deals with some other stuff too, but they don't affect the conditional rendering

````
```
   handleSubmit(e) {
const { groceries, shopping, health, houseNeeds } = this.state;

const gSum = parseInt(groceries, 10);
const sSum = parseInt(shopping, 10);
const hSum = parseInt(health, 10);
const hnSum = parseInt(houseNeeds, 10);

this.setState({
  total: gSum + sSum + hSum + hnSum,
  chartData: [gSum, sSum, hSum, hnSum],
  hasTypedIn: true
 });
  e.preventDefault();
 }
```


```
  {this.state.hasTypedIn ? (
        <BillsChart spendings={this.state.chartData} />
      ) : (
        <ChartCover />
      )}

```
````

Comment: can you also put the functionality of the button when clicked? I mean handleSubmit function

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have a problem with the BillsChart component, perhaps you processing chartData on a BillsChart update.